# WPF ListView with group of RadioButtons and select default value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

Today I have a problem with selected default `CheckBox`. But First i show my code:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding itemsSource, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                    <Expander.Header>
                        <Label Content="{Binding AttrName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </Expander.Header>

                    <ListView Margin="20, 0, 0, 0" ItemsSource="{Binding subItemSource}" BorderBrush="Transparent" >
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding DataContext.AttrName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                                                    Content="{Binding}"
                                                    <!-- What should I bind to to get item checked? -->
                                                    IsChecked={}/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>

                </Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

So i have a nested binding where in CheckBoxes I bind GroupName to parent data context. My `itemsSource` contains the following properties:

```
int DefaultValue { get; set; }
List<int> subItemSource { get; set; }
```

And all I want now is to mark `RadioButton` when actual binding value is equal to `DefaultValue`. How should I do this? Should I write validator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll start by writing a converter class

```
class ElementComparer : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values[0] == values[1];
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

then declare the converter as a resource where l: is your namespace to converter

```
<l:ElementComparer x:Key="ElementComparer"/>
```

then in your data template

```
<DataTemplate>
    <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding DataContext.AttrName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                 Content="{Binding}"
        <RadioButton.IsChecked>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ElementComparer}" Mode="OneWay">
                <Binding Path="DataContext.DefaultValue" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}"/>
                <Binding />
            </MultiBinding>
        </RadioButton.IsChecked>
```

provided the datacontext of the ItemsControl is containing the property for default value to compare with, the trick is to compare the selected item of the list to the current item to detect if it is default item, and will return true from converter and hence radio will be checked

Comment: Great solution. I did not think about using `MultiBinding` here. Great answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Another question - how to implement ConvertBack? I tried to make it TwoWay binding but app crashes with message "Two-way binding requires path or xpath"

Comment: For two way binding you cannot bind `<Binding />` with current item, instead you've to bind some property in the data item. since your item source is int, there is no much possibility in this case, so you need to redesign ur data items before you can use convert back for bindings