# RadioButtons in a ListView. SelectedItem not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, mvvm

Have two properties in my viewmodel, INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented but not shown here. Both Properties are initiated in the constructor and values are set.

```
public ObservableCollection<Foo> Foos { get; init;}
public Foo SelectedFoo { get => _selectedFoo; set => _selectedFoo = value;}
```

the foo class:

```
public class Foo
{
   public string NameOfFoo { get; set; }
   public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

in the corresponding View...

```
<ListView 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Foos}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFoo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        Background="#FF063852" 
        BorderThickness="0">
        
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                
                <RadioButton Content="{Binding NameOfFoo}" 
                             GroupName="GroupSelector" 
                             BorderThickness="0"
                             Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle}"
                             IsChecked="{Binding IsActive}">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectGroupCommand, 
                                                                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                                   CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </RadioButton>
                

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>

        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    </ListView>
```

ItemsSource of ListView is working fine.

The radioButton is not checked as expected after creating new instance from viewmodel.
The command for the event "checked" is ok.
The SETTER from the SelectedFoo propery is never called. Why??

What have I to do, to have the propper radiobutton checked in my view after creation?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24179089/14800168

Multibinding for IsChecked was the trick!